# Cannot access properties of Union Types that the other doesn't contain

Tags: typescript, union-types

I have looked up other posts but I cannot seem to get their solutions to work. I have this union type and this function that uses the `object[]` from that union type, but it throws errors saying `length` doesn't exists because both my types User and Query are not an array of objects.

```js
type Results = object[] | User | Query;

class Pagination implements IPagination
{
    totalPages: any[];
    readonly itemsPerPage = 5;
    
    public async Paginate(items:Results, page: number):Promise<Page>
    {
        const pages = Math.ceil(items.length / this.itemsPerPage); //<- error here

        const paginatedItems = Array.from({ length: pages }, (_, index) => 
        {
            const start = index *  this.itemsPerPage;
            return items.slice(start, start +  this.itemsPerPage); //<- And here because slice is also an array method.
        });

        this.totalPages = [...paginatedItems];
        return { totalPages: this.totalPages, currentPageRows: this.totalPages[page], itemsPerPage: this.itemsPerPage };
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll need to check if it's an array before accessing items.length. Eg, `if (Array.isArray(items))`. What do you want to happen if its not an array?

Comment: Well nothing, I'm only ever passing it as an array into that particular function. I could technically just change the typing there to `object[]` but I wanted to retain using my `Results` type because I use it every where else, my fetch results are used, so I wanted to keep consistency.

Comment: This is how union types work. See [Union Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types)

Comment: I understand, that makes perfect sense. I will check for an array then, and throw a proper error if somehow an array is not passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can carry out checks to ensure that the type of an object is correct before you do any type-specific operations.

More generally, you shouldn't use a union of types in a place where you actually want a very specific type and have code that relies on a certain type being passed.

Something like the following can be used at the top of the method and will prevent invalid types from being used, but a better approach is to ensure that your method signature only accepts types which it can actually use.

```
if (!Array.isArray(items)) {
  return;
}
```